# Fetch data and remove fetched data when click '+' and '-' button using React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, api, button, fetch-api

I am trying to fetch data from database when click '+' button and I am trying to remove those fetched data when click '-' button. But in my code, when I click the '+' button all the parent tags' buttons turned into '-' buttons and when I click the '-' button it does not remove fetched data.

This is my code.

```
  const [isChildOpen, setIsChildOpen] = useState(true);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const onClicktag = (row: any) => {
    setformState(row);
    setModalShow(true);
    setEditTag(true);
    setSelectId(row.id);
  };

  const onClickPlusButton = (row: any) => {
    dispatch(getChildrenTagDetails(row));
    setIsChildOpen(false);
  };
```

This is how the buttons are created.

```
<div className="mt-4">
          {state.tagData.allTagDetails.map((e: any) => {
            return (
            <div onClick={() => onClickPlusButton(e)}>
                  <div
                    style={{
                      height: "20px",
                      width: "20px",
                      border: "1px solid",
                      borderColor: e.color,
                    }}
                    className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"
                  >
                    <span className="ml-4">
                      {isChildOpen ? (
                        <FontAwesomeIcon
                        className="ml-4"
                        icon={faPlus}
                        style={{ color: e.color, cursor: "pointer" }}
                      />
                      ):(
                        <FontAwesomeIcon
                        className="ml-4"
                        icon={faMinus}
                        style={{ color: e.color, cursor: "pointer" }}
                      />
                      )}
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </div>)
</div>
```